# "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a project in which I have a form through which I can edit a question available in a list view. Whenever I select a row from the list view and click on the 'modify' button, the text boxes above the list view load the question and its options.
This means that when I select a row in the list view and click on the 'modify' button, the question loads itself into the text boxes. I edit the question there and click on 'save' to save changes, but I am not able to access the data in the text boxes. It says `{"Input string was not in a correct format."}`.

My code of the form `frmFormWizard`'s 'edit' button is given below:

**frmFormWizard.cs Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SurveyBuilder
{
    public partial class frmFormWizard : Form
    {
        int intPanelNumber = 1;
        Boolean blnCancel = false;
        //int intFlag = 1;

        public frmFormWizard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ...

        private void btnEditTwoOrMoreOptions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int QuestionID;           
            string sql;

            QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(lvTwoOrMoreOptions.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString());
            {
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
                SqlCommand rs = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataReader sdr = null;
                clsConnection clsCon = new clsConnection();

                clsCon.fnc_ConnectToDB(ref cn);

                sql = "";
                sql += "SELECT * FROM SurveyQuestionLog WHERE SurveyQuestionLog.QuestionLogID = "+ QuestionID +"";
                //sql += "SELECT * FROM SurveyQuestionLog";

                rs.Connection = cn;
                rs.CommandText = sql;
                sdr = rs.ExecuteReader();

                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    txtTwoOrMoreQuestions.Text = (string)sdr["Question"];
                    txtOption1.Text = (string)sdr["Choice1"];
                    ...
                }

                sdr.Close();
                rs = null;
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Whenever I try to compile the code it says `"{"Input string was not in a correct format."}"` and this error is shown on the following line:

```
 QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(lvTwoOrMoreOptions.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString());
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: DO NOT USE string concatenation to generate your SQL statements use parameters, otherwise you leave it open to SQL injection.

Comment: What is the runtime value of lvTwoOrMoreOptions.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString()?  Also, shouldn't "Text" already be a string, making .ToString() redundant?

Comment: What @Lloyd says is true: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Nolonar what does that have to do with C#, string concatenation and parameters?

Comment: @Default It's got nothing to do with C#, it's about SQL. Since SQL statements are strings, you can "inject" commands to SQL by writing valid SQL statements where variables are expected. When you concatenate strings to generate SQL statements, a user may abuse of this as described in the comic. That's basically what Lloyd and Randall Munroe from xkcd are trying to convey. Of course, you *could* concatenate the strings and still be safe from SQL injection, but using parameters instead of concatenation is the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like some space include in the text.
Use

> lvTwoOrMoreOptions.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString().Trim()

and convert to int32.

hope this code will solve you

From comments

if your ListView is in report mode (i.e. it looks like a grid) then you will need the SubItems property. `lvTwoOrMoreOptions.SelectedItems` gets you each items in the list view - SubItems gets you the columns. So `lvTwoOrMoreOptions.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0]` is the first column value,

Comment: @Ayesha Noor: What is the run time value of  lvTwoOrMoreOptions.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString()

Comment: @Ayesha Noor: if your ListView is in report mode (i.e. it looks like a grid) then you will need the SubItems property. lvTwoOrMoreOptions.SelectedItems gets you each items in the list view - SubItems gets you the columns. So lvTwoOrMoreOptions.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0] is the first column value, try this. if your issue solved please mark my answer as solution

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code like below.

```
  int QuestionID;

  bool IsIntValue = Int32.TryParse("YOUR-VARIABLE", out QuestionID);

  if (IsIntValue)
  {
      // YOUR CODE HERE  
  }
```

Hope i will be help.

Answer (score 1):

> whenever i try to compile the code it says "{"Input string was not in a correct format."}"

This error won't come on compiling.

Now the error comese because you are trying to parse an invalid string to integer. To do it in a safe manner, you should do it like this

```
int questionID;
if(int.TryParse(vTwoOrMoreOptions.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString(),out questionID))
{
//success code
}
else
{
 //failure code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that whatever that text is containing some characters which cannot be converted to integer like space, letters, special characters etc. Check what is coming through dropdown as below

`lvTwoOrMoreOptions.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString();`

and see if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to access a control inside a control, maybe a GridView or DetailsView.

Try using something like this:

```
empsalary = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)DetailsView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text);
```