# Get a cell value in gridview selected row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Implemented the  code  below it gives a run time error."Input string was not in a correct format".

```
int ID = int.Parse(grdMnaualEntryTransactionTemplate.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text)
```

Comment: What is the `.Text` value? Is it a number?

Comment: number, I tried Value instead of Text but  it  gives me build errors

Comment: can you provide markup for your grid?

Comment: I think in your database datatype may be different. Put a break point and check in the quickWatch what you are getting in "grdMnaualEntryTransactionTemplate.SelectedRow.Cells[1]" and then try to add manipulate it in the Immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331409/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format) post also. Error can be occurred due to extra spacing. Try to use .Trim() and check.

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
int ID = int.Parse(grdMnaualEntryTransactionTemplate.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
```

Or...

```
int ID = (int)grdMnaualEntryTransactionTemplate.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Value;
```

Comment: It gives  me this error 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedRows' and no extension method 'SelectedRows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)