# Input string not in correct format (Radiobuttonlist) asp.net

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to retrieve the text from a radiobutton to use in my sql query.
I typed in this:

```
 int cardtype = int.Parse(rbcard.SelectedItem.Text);
```

and an error occurs

```
 Input string not in correct format
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Input string was not in a correct format."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331409/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Comment: Doesn't seem to help me solve. why is it a duplicate

Comment: That was a listview. This is a radiobuttonlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say radio button list look like :

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdID" runat="server">

<asp:ListItem Text ="Item1" Value="1" />
<asp:ListItem Text ="Item2" Value="2" />
<asp:ListItem Text ="Item3" Value="3" />
<asp:ListItem Text ="Item4" Value="4" />

</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

then to get selected value do:

```
string selectedValue = rdID.SelectedValue;
        Response.Write(selectedValue);
```

Then after getting the value as string, then you can parse it as int like:

```
int x = Int32.Parse(selectedValue );
```

Hopefully this can help you

Comment: my pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are actually trying to parse the text of the radio button list item and not the value.

Your code looks correct to me, I would just make sure you check that an item is selected before you try and parse the int.

**HTML**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbcard" runat="server">

<asp:ListItem Text ="1" Value="1" />
<asp:ListItem Text ="2" Value="2" />
<asp:ListItem Text ="3" Value="3" />
<asp:ListItem Text ="4" Value="4" />

</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="select value" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbcard.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            int cardtype = int.Parse(rbcard.SelectedItem.Text);
            Label1.Text = "You Selected: " + cardtype;
        }
    }
```